# Local geolocation to FIPS county using Latitude and Longitude

Tags: geocoding, tiger, reverse-geocoding, united-states, fips

I have millions of lat,long pairs which I want to convert to FIPS county codes that match with the US census data. In the past I used the census block api but that is too slow for the amount of numbers that I have. Is there a better library / tool that I can load locally ? If not would be possible to use the TIGER data from the census website to create a service like that ? What knowledge is required (projections, minimum distances, ...) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check out http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/ a ready to use virtual machine(VM) for geocoding and reverse geocoding, it provides useful information including FIPS codes.

i hope it will help.

Comment: That link is just a mine of excellent stuff !

Comment: Yes, @fabrizioM Its a really power toolkit to do offline geocoding & reverse geocoding.

Comment: Is there anyone offering a paid hosted service? I want to convert my lat/longs to FIPS codes, but I'd prefer to pay a small monthly fee instead of hosting this service myself.

Comment: @Lucas. Please check out http://www.fcc.gov/developer/census-block-conversions-api. I hope it will help.

Comment: The link appears to no longer work.

Answer (score 3):

See this FFC site, it has moved: https://geo.fcc.gov/api/census/#!/area/get_area

And some python 3 code to get the data:

```
import urllib, json, requests

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://geo.fcc.gov/api/census/area?lat=42.3295&lon=-71.0826&format=json") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    print(data)

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

print(data['results'][0]['state_fips'])
print(data['results'][0]['county_fips'])
print(data['results'][0]['county_name'])
```

Comment: Has this API been taken down? The example URL gives me a 502 error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FCC Conversion API](https://www.fcc.gov/general/census-block-conversions-api)

For example:
    http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/find?format=json&latitude=28.35975&longitude=-81.421988&showall=true

Comment: That API has been deprecated.  @Martien's answer has the replacement API.